# Prevent DIV from moving when scaling

Tags: html, css

I am making a website, where I want a certain div to be always visible in the center of the window. Next to that div, both on the left and right side, I want to have another div that stays next to the centered div. The centered div may be shorter than the two side divs. The hard part however is that when the window is scaled smaller, I don't want the (right) side div to move under the shorter center div, but to stay next to it and eventually be hidden when only the centered div is shown.

The fiddle below illustrates what the desired situation is and what the actual situation is. All three boxes (red = 1, green = 2, blue = 3) are shown when there is enough width. But when the window is scaled down, only 2 should be visible. However, now when there is not enough space to display 3, it moves underneath 2. I want it to stay next to 2 and just be invisible, just like box 1.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="innerleft">
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: red;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="innercenter">
        <div style="width: 500px; height: 100px; background-color: green;">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerright">
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: blue;">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: purple;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.innerleft {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:-300px;
}
.innercenter {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.innerright {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9thXH/)

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `margin-left:-300px;` with `right: calc(50% + 250px);` in `.innerleft` and then adding `left: calc(50% + 250px);` to `.innerright` does the trick.

What is being done here is that I've set the distance from the left and right side of the divs to something that can't be changed by resizing or scaling the page.

The calculation is `50%` from the side, + 50% of the center div's width.

This solution only works when you have a static width for the center div that can't/won't be changed.

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2K5v8/)

Comment: Your answer indeed does the trick, thanks for your fast reply! It would be even better though to have a similar solution where the width of the center div doesn't have to be fixed, but for now this will do.